# Word for person unwilling to share information

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

What do you call a person who is unwilling to share information?

Comment: Unwilling to share what kind of information? With whom? Under which circumstances? For what reasons? You have to be more precise, otherwise you'll get a dozen answers that are all equally right, and all equally wrong.

Answer (score 7):

One possibility is to use:

> **reticent** (n.): not willing to provide information about
>   something, especially about yourself or your feelings.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Mehper's answer, I'd suggest *[discreet](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/discreet)* might be a good word, if you mean this in the approving sense, or *[close](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/close)* (meaning 18: Secretive; reticent: "was close about her personal life"
) otherwise. *[Secretive](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/secretive)* might also apply in extreme cases.

Answer (score 3):

I would use secretive.

> Secretive: inclined to secrecy or reticence about divulging information.

Answer (score 1):

I would submit: *Paranoid*.

Use with caution.

Answer (score 1):

If it is about private information, the person could be said to be *privacy aware*.